# Test Unit environment does not recognize specific types

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing

I am trying to run a unit test for a wpf application.

I'm trying to run this bit of code:

```
public static void CreateScreenshot(Visual target, string fileName)
        {
            if (target == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
            {
                return;
            }
}
```

However the test solution does not recognize Visual as a type.
I tried adding references for it, however that's been unsuccessfull.
I'm either trying to add wrong references or I'm missing something.

What reference should I add?

Comment: This is most definitely a reference error. Most probably you are referencing the wrong thing.Unless there is a version difference between your unit test and your wpf application. Meaning .net framework and .net core. Which are two noncompatible runtimes.

Comment: @panoskarajohn I did use .NET (framework) for Unit Tests. As for the reference I'm not sure what to add. I tried System.Windows.Media and System.Windows.DependancyObject, but none of them could be found when I searched for the references.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.visual?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: It is in System.Windows.Media. Please make sure both your projects are .net framework